# Rails 4: How do I delete a nested object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a user model and a nested model "Entries" like that:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :entries
  ...

end
```

entry.rb

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  ...

end
```

user/show.html.erb

```
<p><%= link_to 'Destroy', remove_entry_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
    resources :entries
end
...
delete "remove_entry" => "entries#destroy", :as => "remove_entry"
```

entries_controller.rb

```
def destroy

    @user = current_user
    @user.entries.find(params[:id]).destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_path(current_user), notice: 'Entry was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end

  end
```

And I get this error:

Couldn't find Entry without an ID

on this line

```
@user.entries.find(params[:id]).destroy
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `params[:id]` is `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an id to this route:

```
delete "remove_entry" => "entries#destroy", :as => "remove_entry"
```

The remove_entry route, doesn't have a positional parameter for id, and in your call to remove_entry_path, you don't provide an id param.

That is why in your controller action, params[:id] == nil

**Solution**

Pass an id

```
<p><%= link_to 'Destroy', remove_entry_path(id: @entry.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
```

or add a positional parameter in the route and pass the id to the url helper.

```
# config/routes.rb
delete "remove_entry/:id" => "entries#destroy", :as => "remove_entry"
```

and

```
<!-- in view -->
<p><%= link_to 'Destroy', remove_entry_path(id: @entry.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving `params[:id]` as `nil` and that's why you are getting this error

> Couldn't find Entry without an ID

Pass `@entry` object with the route helper

```
<p><%= link_to 'Destroy', remove_entry_path(@entry), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
```

Comment: The same outcome. I have a loop of all entries that belong to this user in user -> show view like that "current_user.entries.each do |entry|". I tried passing "entry" and it won't work. Neither did passing @entry. Maybe I'm missing some detail? I'm new to rails...

Comment: this works if you change the route: `delete "remove_entry/:id" => "entries#destroy", :as => "remove_entry"`